# Is there a way to pass selected date from date_popup to another view in URL?

Tags: datetime, views

I'm using date module in Drupal 7. There are two views that I created; a link inside of one leads to another view. In the first view, I used exposed popup date filter to get the result. What I'm trying to achieve here is how to pass the selected date from the date popup, put it in the URL to use as contextual filter in the another view.

Thanks,
Jake

Answer (score 0):

Definitely. When you expose a filter, it listens for a specific $_GET ID in the URL. This ID can be set by expanding the "More" settings of the particular filter item and entering/modifying the string in the "Filter identifier" field.

In your case, you'd copy the first View's filter identifier and paste it into the second View's filter identifier, thus allowing both of them to use the same item in the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Charlie. I tried the way you suggested, but it did not work. This is what I'm doing. My view has exposed filter which allow user to select a date range (from, to). I have a link in the return result to the second page which is the drill down version of the first page.

Comment: When I select the link, it opens the view with date range defined in the 2nd view. I did name the same second View's filter as the first one.